# Create Dependant Data Validation without Cell Tables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have data validation setup for cell **A1** to select either "dog" or "fruit".  I have another data validation for cell **A2** to allow the user to pick items depending on the value picked for cell **A1**.  I am using this formula:

```
=IF(A1="fruit",C1:C4,D1:D4)
```

[image]

All this is working.
What I now want to do is change the formula so the **A2** options are directly in the formula rather than in worksheet cells.

I have tried:

```
=IF(A1="fruit",{"apple","peach","cherry","blueberry"},{"bulldog","boxer","poodle","pug"})
```

But this does not work.  Any suggestions??

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use array constants for data validation.

Comment: Try creating a named range with those constants and using that in your data validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make C1:C4 a named range called "List_Fruit"
2. Make D1:D4 a named range called "List_Dogs"
   (These could also be defined dynamically)
3. Make the data validation list source `=INDIRECT("List_"&A1)`

Should work.

[image]